# Login to website with multiple user name with at same time

Tags: c#, browser

I have 4 different email ids at gmail.I need to make an application that lets has tabbed pages of browser and lets me login with various emails all i have to do is select tabs i want to .My first approach was to make c# application having different user agents and multiple web browsers but that was eventually fail because browsers share COM layes.is there any other way?

Comment: You can try to prevent the site from placing a login cookie.

Comment: can we create seperate cokie for each login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you need to write something.  I think I've read that the next release of Chrome will allow this and [it is already possible in IE](http://www.walkernews.net/2009/03/25/how-to-login-multiple-gmail-accounts-with-ie8/).

Comment: There are also extensions or work arounds for the other main browsers - http://maketecheasier.com/login-to-multiple-accounts-on-the-same-website-simultaneously/2009/05/12

Comment: What is the feasibility of having c# web control operating seperatly

Comment: nice find, **-nomerge** to the rescue

Comment: Session clearing works and lets me able to ligin on same site as A and B but further surfing makes both controls have same user either A or B.

Comment: is there any way to keep these further isolated